# Transform values from 1 column to multiple columns

Tags: pandas

I have the following table:

[image]

and would like to convert the product column to something like:

[image]

How would you recomend I do this in pandas? Test df below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test_dict = {'Acount': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'Product': [np.nan, 'A','A,B,C', 'C']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_dict)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a single column you can use `Series.str.get_dummies` which allows you to specify the character that separates all categories. Set `'Acount'` to the index so that appears in the output:

```
df.set_index('Acount')['Product'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')

        A  B  C
Acount         
1       0  0  0
2       1  0  0
3       1  1  1
4       0  0  1
```

Comment: Better solution!  +1  Nice @ALollz.

Answer (score 4):

Let's use `.str.split`, `explode` and `pd.crosstab`:

```
df_count = df.assign(Product=df['Product'].str.split(',')).explode('Product')
pd.crosstab(df_count['Acount'], df_count['Product']).reindex(df['Acount'].unique(), fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
Product  A  B  C
Acount          
1        0  0  0
2        1  0  0
3        1  1  1
4        0  0  1
```

### Details

Let's `assign` 'Product' as a list of elements using `.str.split` on commas.
Next, use `explode` to unnest the list in the 'Product' column.
Now, use `pd.crosstab` to count the occurrence for each value by 'Acount'.
Lastly, `reindex` to fill missing 'Acount' not present in crosstab.